# how do i filter items by property in ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I have some data and a select control as you can see from my code sample below. It works for me but I want to be able to filter the data by type. In my code sample, I show one way I have tried to filter the data based on the type being a value of one. I am not sure if the way I am creating the select is causing this simple inline filter to not work or if I am doing something wrong?

```
$scope.data = [{ 
name : "5 play",
type : 1
}, {
name : "one on one",
type : 2}, {
name : "two on one",
type : 2}];

<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedRule" 
ng-options="item as (item.Name) for item in data track by item.Name | filter:{type:1}"></select>
```

Comment: not sure if it will fix it but track by should always be at the end

Comment: @juvian, that was it....so stupid of me. thanks. write it as the answer and I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in angular docs, track by must always be the last expression:

> Note: track by must always be the last expression

My guess is that all that follows is not considered, so that´s why your filter wasn´t applying. Moving the track by to the right place should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as mentioned. Move the `track by` at the end and make the letter `N` lowercase like in the following demo or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jwe5d5me/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: "5 play",
    type: 1
  }, {
    name: "one on one",
    type: 2
  }, {
    name: "two on one",
    type: 2
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedRule" ng-options="item as item.name for item in data | filter:{type:1} track by item.name"></select>
</div>
```